# How do I fetch the KML's style information using fastkml?

Tags: python, performance, xml-parsing, kml

I am parsing a KML and need to split features depending on the style given to each feature.
I've managed to parse the features and grab the styleUrl of each feature.
Here is roughly how I grab the styleUrls as well as the attributes from the features :

```
from fastkml import kml
with open( os.path.join(tmp_root,'doc.kml')) as file:
    for text in file : 
        #print (text). It's not "pretty print", all in one line.
        k = kml.KML()
        k.from_string(text)
        document = list(k.features())
        print(len(document)) #this is the "<Document id=xxx ", should be equal to 1
        # Fetching styles code should go here
        folders = list(document[0].features())
        print(folders) # two folders, one for boundaries and one for points
        for folder in folders :
            features = list(folder.features())
            for f in features : 
                print(f.name)
                print(f.styleUrl)
                print (f.extended_data.elements) 
                for attribute in f.extended_data.elements :
                    print(attribute.name, attribute.value)
                # if styleUrl == style.id, do something
```

My issue is trying to fetch the information from the Styles section of the Document. I can access the style's ID, but that's about it.

```
stylesSection = document[0].styles() #similar to how I access folders
for style in stylesSection : 
    print(style) # <fastkml.styles.Style object at 0x0000029C0599CFD0>
    print(style.id) #styleid
    print(style.styles) # <bound method Style.styles of <fastkml.styles.Style object at 0x0000029C057A97C0>>
```

I believe that **style.styles** is the function found [here](https://fastkml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_guide.html#fastkml.styles.Style)

Here's what the beginning of the document looks like :

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document id="IDOFDOC">
    <name>NAME</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Style id="styleid">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <width>5</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <fill>0</fill>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
```

How do I fetch the **color**, **width** and **fill** attributes of the Poly and Line Styles that are in the **<Style>** ? Would the process be the same for a **<StyleMap>** ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can say list(style.styles())[0].color in order to get what you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).